# Echo blob in xml

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to show the Base64 images storeds (blob) in MySQL in xml as base64 string.
but the I'm getting this error:

> Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.

Here is my code

> if($_GET['id'] != '')
>    {

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM CDUsers WHERE id =  '.$_GET['id']; } else {   $sql = 'SELECT * FROM CDUsers'; }
 $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
$row =  mysql_num_rows($result);
 header('Content-type: text/xml');  
 if($row != 0) {?>  
 <CDUsers><?php while($user = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))       
  { ?>      
<user>
<user_foto><?php echo($user['foto']);?></user_foto>

            </user><?php    
} ?>    </CDUsers><?php 
 } else     {   
?>      <CDUsers>   
    <user>vazio</user> 
    </CDUsers><?php
```

}    ?>

Comment: WHAT is the actual error btw?

Answer (score 0):

blobs are not base64 stored.

it's just phpMyAdmin's presentation of the binary.

```
<?php echo(base64_encode($user['foto'])); ?>
```